# PHP Multiple Tasks One File

Tags: php

I am learning the php game - and am in need of completing two tasks in one .php file.  What I need is

1) Connect To Server

2) Execute Stored Procedure (runs an insert into statement)

3) When stored proc fully executes run select statement against table

4) Echo the results

This is my syntax -> and I get an error that the table `tablecreatedfromproc` does not exist.  Is the `Select` statement firing before the stored proc fully executes?  If I run the stored procedure manually, it executes as it should (meaning it is valid syntax) - but when I try to run it from my php file I get the error.

How should this syntax be updated so that it executes as I need it to?

```
//connection string
$hostname = 'hostname';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$password");

//Parsing the passed in data
$passedparams = implode(',',$_REQUEST['passedparams']);

//Capturing the dates from passed in data
$d1 = $_REQUEST['d1'];
$d2 = $_REQUEST['d2'];

//Run Stored Procedure To Create Table
$proc = mssql_init('HoldingPattern',$conn);
mssql_bind($proc,'@d1',$d1,SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_bind($proc,'@d2',$d2,SQLVARCHAR);

//Create Query String to query newly created table
$sql = "SELECT ".$passedparams." FROM tablecreatedfromproc";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: the error explains the problem `and I get an error that the table tablecreatedfromproc does not exist` , you need to create the table before you query it;

Comment: @hassan - the table is created in the stored procedure which I am executing first in the php. (or at least think I am)

Comment: how do you connect to mssql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using PDO to connect, in the same time that you are trying to execute another function `mssql_*` -*which is removed in php7*-

use PDO to [execute your procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) ,

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("HoldingPattern");
$stmt->bindParam(/* your required parameters goes here */);
$stmt->execute();
```

as mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#68398):

> If you need to get Output variable from MSSQL stored procedure, try this :

```
-- PROCEDURE
CREATE PROCEDURE spReturn_Int @err int OUTPUT
AS
SET @err = 11
GO

$sth = $dbh->prepare("EXECUTE spReturn_Int ?");
$sth->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
$sth->execute();
print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
```

Comment: How would I bind my parameters?  The example you linked to shows an output and an input/output - I only need input params.

Comment: `$sth->bindParam(xxx, xxx, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);` as following